"The account does not exist in the Cloud API" - Whatsapp Business API problem with test number
In the page setup on Meta For Developers it says that the account (test number) does not exist in the Cloud API.
I was previously able to run tests normally with the provided test number (receiving messages on my personal phone), but since yesterday afternoon, I've been getting some message like:

"Failed to send message. The account does not exist in the Cloud API. Use the /register API to create an account first."

Making the request in Postman, I have the following response:
"error": {
    "message": "The account is not registered",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 133010,
    "error_subcode": 2593006,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "The account does not exist",
    "error_user_msg": "The account does not exist in the Cloud API. Use /register API to create an account first.",
    "fbtrace_id": "A6fN7xoCSrj2t1dW_Qvv5d0"
}

In my Flutter project (VSCode), the Debug Console also shows:

"flutter: {error: {message: The account is not registered, type: OAuthException, code: 133010, error_subcode: 2593006, is_transient: false,..."

Despite my best efforts, I've reached a dead end... help me please.
I've tried everything I can think of: checking all the API settings, sending messages to different numbers, reviewing the documentation, and searching the internet for similar issues. But nothing seems to work. I just need to get the tests running again.

Hi,
Did U found any solution?
Thanks

I have found that addition step needed -
the phone number need to be "registered".
Just call the "register" endpoint with the body
{ 
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "pin": "******"
}

Registeretion Docs
